# PHP Mail error - Unable to send message to SMTP server. No recipients specified. ite. ready. in

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am trying to using a simple php email

This is working in my production server. But this is not working in my development server. I am not able to find what server configuration is missing

i am getting the error

```
Unable to send message to SMTP server. No recipients specified. ite. ready. in  "filepath" on line 17
```

What is this **ite**?

```
$toemail="me@example.com";
 $subject="subject line" ;
  $content="conetent message";
$frmemail = "From:you@example.com" ;
    mail( $toemail,$subject,$content,$frmemail ) ;
```

Can anyone suggest what configuration or php ini setting am missing

dev i access on a port .

i saw the exact same error here

http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=134654

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?t=5151&f=77#p23409

but what can be the some security settings blocking sending email from a different domain??

```
ZMAil

SMTP  localhost  
smtp_port  25  
sendmail_from  no value
```

Comment: you may have a malformed header, plz post whats in `$frmemail`.

Comment: there is no big code ..anyway i updated it

Comment: Are you on shared hosting? This may be worth asking the hosting provider about

Comment: @Pekka `This is working in my production server`

Comment: @Gabriel well, either way, he should probably ask the person who is managing it :)

Comment: @Pekka he is managing the server, because he said `this is not working in my development server.`.

Hosting provider = Production server
Local server = @zod Server

Comment: @Gabriel ahh, you're right, I somehow managed to misread this :)

Comment: hey atleast can you give a hint .. what all php info cofiguration or server config to check for sending mail

Comment: i recently upgraded my dev to PHP Version 5.3.8-ZS5.5.0 

 but prod is till in  5.3.6

Comment: @zod Have you changed your PHP SMTP settings?

Comment: the current setting i updated

Comment: I think you may have four error messages there, and the `ite.` belongs to `site.`; `ready.` is the end of another one; and `in "filepath" on line 17` is still another. It is possible to do domain-specific checking [but you can look that up just as well as I can] but sorting out the error reporting might also be worthwhile, as you obviously do have recipients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing these settings on the server seems to have allowed the email to be sent successfully.  The settings changed were:

```
AUTOADD(*YES)

ALWRLY(*ALL)
```

Allow rely mail is the main one

Answer (score 0):

The fourth parameter - additional headers - is optional. If is not set the sendmail_from option from php.ini will be used.
If you have access to the php.ini file, try to set the option to you@example.com and remove the 4th argument from mail() function.